# Debug Assertion Error - delete call on char pointer

Tags: c++, string, memory-management

So I decided to dwelve a bit within the pesty C++.

When I call the delete function on a pointer to a simple class that I created I'm greeted by a `Debug Assertion Failure -Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)`. I assume this is because I've handled the string manipulation wrong and thus causing memory corruption.

I created a basic class, [I]animal[/I], that has a string defined that can be set through a function.

```
// name
char * ptrName;

animal::animal(char * name)
{
 this->SetName(name);
};

animal::~animal()
{
 delete [] ptrName;
}

void animal::SetName(char * name)
{
 ptrName = name;
};
```

When using the above class as shown below the error occurs. I've tried both `delete ptrName` and `delete [] ptrName` but to no avail.

```
animal * cat = new animal("Optimus Prime");
delete cat;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I decided to dwelve a bit within the pesty C++.

Then do yourself a favor and use C++ *right*. That would be to use `std::string`:

```
// name
std::string name_;

animal::animal(const std::string& name)
  : name_(name)
{
}

//animal::~animal() // not needed any longer

//note: copying also automatically taken care of by std::string
//animal(const animal&)
//animal& operator=(const animal&)

void animal::SetName(const std::string& name)
{
 name_ = name;
}
```

Have a look at ***[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)***. I'd recommend ***Accelerated C++***. It comes with a steep learning curve, but since you already know a bit of C++, it's the 250 pages that might set you on the right track.

As a rule of thumb: *Whenever you release a resource (memory or other), and it's not **in the destructor of a class whose solely purpose is to manage this one resource**, something is wrong with your design.* Personally, I become suspicious whenever I feel the need to write a destructor, copy constructor, or assignment operator.

Comment: I ordered Accelerated C++ from Amazon just now. What is the reason for not needing to deallocate the name_ variable when you set it to a new value?

Comment: All the logic of allocating and deallocating is hidden behind std::string.

Comment: @Qua: When it's `std::string`, then that class takes care of memory management for you. When it's C strings (pointers to the first character of a dynamically allocated array), you have to do it manually. But then you also have to keep track of which pointer really points to a dynamically allocated array.A string literal isn't dynamically allocated, so it doesn't need to be `delete[]`'d. But inside of your class you don't know whether a pointer handed in points to a dynamically allocated array. So you have to always copy it into your own array and leave...

Comment: ...managing the pointer handed in to the caller. The fact that this is error-prone is one of the main reasons C++ with its abstraction mechanisms was invented in the first place. I suppose a string class was among the first dozen of classes ever written for C++. Now that we have `std::string` just use that.

Comment: Excellent insight into topics that aren't that dominant in the world of .NET.

Answer (score 2):

The string `"Optimus Prime"` was not dynamically allocated, and thus it is not correct to call `delete` on it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from deleting a pointer that you don't own. You haven't allocated the string, so you must not delete it. The C string you are using is allocated statically by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the `setName` function you are merely assigning the name to ptrName. In the example, the name is a const char string pointer which you can't delete (it is not allocated on the heap). To avoid this error, you can either use a std::string in the class or allocate a new char arry in the constructor of the `animal` class and assign the pointer to it. Then, in the destructor you can delete the array.

Answer (score 1):

Who has ownership of your string?

For example, when you construct your new animal, you're passing in a string literal - that's not yours to free.

You should consider avoiding char* and just using std::string instead.

If you have to use char*, think about ownership.  For example, one option is for you to take a copy of the string (using strdup) and own that.  This way you can't be stuck with strange bugs like this

```
char* szFoo = strdup("my string");
{
  animal a(szFoo);
}
// At this point szFoo has been deleted by the destructor of a
// and bad things will start to happen here.
printf("The value of my string %s",szFoo);
```